# Determining if a hashtag refers to a location at the town/city level using the Google geolocation APIs

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, location

So I'm making a service which searches for a specific hashtag and then attempts to place the origin of those tweets on a map.

There are three methods for determining the location. One is doing a reverse lookup on the geolocation data, which is only available on a small portion of tweets (< 10%). The second is looking for a hashtag in the tweet specifying a location and the third is looking at the users profile.

The one I'm currently having a problem with is the second. I have no problem extracting the tweets and caching the results but the results are currently extremely fuzzy because Google is very good search. For example if I search for "followme" (obviously unintended to be interpreted as an address) then Google manages to find a street called "Follow Me" in Victoria, Australia.

Basically what I'm looking to do is only search at a town or city level to reduce the number of false positives. But I haven't been able to find any documentation which could help me with that.

**Edit:** Alternatively, are there any map providers that do support this kind of functionality?

**Edit 2:** Responding to the request for code and some more explanation.

The code probably is incomplete and isn't very helpful. All you really need to know about it is:

1. It runs as in a cron with the aim to populate a database.
2. It will query the twitter API, looking for a specific hashtag
3. If it can't find any geolocation data (which needs to be specifically enabled by the user) to do a reverse lookup on the address then it falls back to relying on hashtags in the tweet body.
4. I will filter that data to remove duplicates and ignore any terms which already exist in the datbase.
5. On the remaining items, I need do an address search on those hashtags (formatted into a list of terms) to see if any of them match a town or city name. **If I just do a straight up search then I will get back a whole bunch of false positives.**

http://pastebin.com/HX2vt0Mh

For an example of a false positive. If I pass in "followme" derived from the hashtag "#followme" then I will get "Follow Me‎, Lysterfield VIC 3156, Australia". If I limit that search to just a town level then false positives should come down to an acceptable level.

Comment: Are you using `Direction Service`? Please, show some of your code, so we can help better

Comment: Updated. Problem is there isn't much to show, if I can just find a bit of the Maps API that allows me to so this then I can start putting it together a bit better. But I can't find anything right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may look at this:

1. [Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder)
2. And filter the [GeocoderResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderResult) by [GeocodingAddressTypes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingAddressTypes)

Consider the following exemple (and look at the Chrome's console):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Geocoding service</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; min-height: 600px; min-width: 700px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
      #panel { position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 50%; margin-left: -180px; z-index: 5; background-color: #fff; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #999; }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="panel">
      <input id="address" type="textbox" value="followme">
      <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <script>
        var geocoder;
        var map;

        var filterTypes = ["country", "administrative_area_level_1", "administrative_area_level_2", "administrative_area_level_3", "locality"];

        function initialize() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        }

        function codeAddress() {
            var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                    for (var i = 0;i < results.length; i++) {
                        var resultTypes = results[i].types;
                        for (var j = 0; j < resultTypes.length; j++) {
                            for (var type in filterTypes) {
                                if (filterTypes[type] == resultTypes[j]) {
                                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                        map: map,
                                        //draggable: true,
                                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                                    });
                                    console.log("The result is of good type");
                                } 
                                console.log(resultTypes[j]);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                }
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As another option you can look at this:

1. [Place](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlacesService)
2. [TextSearchRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#TextSearchRequest)
3. And filter the [PlaceResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult) by [supported_types#table2](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types#table2)

Comment: So, what you're saying is that you have to compare the types AFTER the results have been retrieved? You can't limit the actual search?

Comment: Well thanks, I can't award the bounty at the moment but I will when the timer runs out.

Comment: With `Places` you can limit the query by [types](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types#table2) but I'm not sure about the results it will throw.
With `Geocoder` you can limit the query by _region_, but since you don't have this information before searching it won't help. So, basically yes with google.maps is what you have.